# Swift PerfectServer: POST request and JSON body

Tags: ios, swift, perfect

first of all I'd like to thank the team for this amazing project, it is indeed exiting to be able to start writing server-side software in Swift.

I'm successfully running a POC using PerfectServer on an Ubuntu VM and working on the API to interact with the mobile client.

There is one aspect I didn't quite understand yet, and that is accessing the request body data from my PerfectServer Handler.

Here is the workflow I have in mind:

- The client submits a POST request to PerfectServer including some
  JSON encoded body data
- Once that hits the "valuesForResponse:" of
  my server side Handler, I retrieve the WebRequest representation of
  my request successfully
- The request object does expose a many
  properties of the HTTP request, including headers and the url-like
  formatted query parameters.

Unfortunately, I cannot see a way to retrieve the underlying request body data. I would expect that to be some kind of public properties exposing the raw data that my handle can retrieve and decode in order to process the request.

The only example provided in the Examples workspace that comes with the project and sends a POST request that includes a body is in the project Authenticator. Here the HTTP body part takes the form os a UTF-8 encoded string where the values are query-params-like formatted.

name=Matteo&password=mypassword

This gets somehow exposed on the server handler by the WebRequest "param" property, that in the inner implementation of HTTPServer seems to expect an "&" separated string of key-values:

What I would expect is to have a way to provide body data in whatever form / encoding needed, in my case a JSON form:

{"name":"Matteo", "password":"psw"}

and be able to access that data from the WebRequest in my handler, decode it and use it to serve the request.
To summarise, I assume you could say that a WebRequest.bodyData public property is what I am after here :).

Is there something I am missing here?
Thanks in advance for any clarification!

Comment: from the source: https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect/blob/master/PerfectLib/WebRequest.swift, there is a property in the request called: postBodyBytes. From the comment, it said if you post json, you can get the body as bytes array.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've been an idiot in not updating the project for over 2 weeks, apparently it's a fairly new addition...which explains why there's no trace of it in my version.

Comment: Yeah, just check the history. It is newly added.